# How to return random string only once?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have searched high and low to find an answer, but can't seem to find one anywhere.

```
<?php
$f_contents = file("x.txt"); 
$line = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
echo($line);
?>
```

Currently I am getting random results on every page load, but need to return the string only once. I am using Wordpress, so I would preferably like a way to do this only when a page is created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only once between all page loads?

Comment: Where did you put this code? which file?

Comment: Yes only once Jason. The code is within page content, inside of a list. The file is a text document with links, one per row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP built in `uniqid()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: This isn't going to load from the OP's file though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a piece of meta information to your page when it gets created.

You can do this by creation your own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add an option containing the posts ID and only set this option if it doesn't yet exist.

```
function random_option($id, $file){

if(get_option("rand_option".$id))
     return get_option("rand_option".$id);

$f_contents = file($file); 
$value = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
add_option( "rand_option".$id, $value );

return $value;

}
```

then call it:

```
echo random_option(get_the_ID(), "file.txt");
```

Comment: or if you only want to return it once across all page loads set the first return to 0